# Unable to push to remote repo in a directory with local git configuration

Tags: git, push

I have a special directory which has a local git configuration that is different from the user git configuration. See the following screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, the user name is `title-case` and the user email is `18871315325@163.com`. However, when I use `git push origin main` to push datas, an error occurs `ERROR: Permission to title-case/title-case.github.io.git denied to SwitWu. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

I'm not sure whether I have provided enough information. If not, please tell me. Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user.name` and `user.email` fields there have **nothing whatsoever** to do with authentication to GitHub, GitLab, or any other remote host. Those fields are only there to make sure that commits are attributed to the right person. You can change them every time you push or pull or clone, and it won't affect the outcome of your push or pull or clone.

You're getting that message because your SSH connection to GitHub is happening using the key that GitHub associates with its `SwitWu` account. If you want `SwitWu` to be able to push and pull on that repo, then grant that user that permission; otherwise, to push as `title-case` using SSH, then you'll need to use a different key associated with the `title-case` account.

To set up multiple SSH keys for multiple GitHub (or GitLab, etc.) accounts,

1. Create the new key, or use one that is not already associated with another account
2. Add the public key to the account or repo, as appropriate
3. Update `~/.ssh/config` in your favorite editor:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_userA # path to your main account's key
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host userB.github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_userB # path to your second account's key
  IdentitiesOnly yes

# repeat for as many keys/identities as you like, and name the `Host` and key files whatever works best for you
```

4. If you already have repos that should use `userB`, then `git remote set-url origin git@userB.github.com:owner/repo.git` from those repos.
5. If you need to clone repos as `userB`, then `git clone git@userB.github.com:owner/repo.git`

Pushes, pulls, and other Git commands that reference the network will only know the remote as `origin` (or whatever other name you give it), so once this is done then SSH will handle the different credentials behind the scenes.

Comment: Nice answer! It helps me resolve my problem. Thank you@Jim Redmond